# Loop through collection and find documents where name equals in firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make as much logic in the firebase cloud functions, but not sure how to! Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
const myGroups = admin.firestore().collection('groups').find({"playerId":userId});
```

I know that above is not correct, but i cant seem to find a solution for this. I would like to get all my groups into an array or something and send them back to my app.

I am not sure if this is wise?!? But think that it would be easier to add or change to the script from one place, instead of all devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you need to use firestore compound queries you can find the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

so in your case the code will look something like:

`const myGroups = await admin.firestore().collection('groups').where("playerId", "==", userId}).get();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get()` on the [`CollectionReference`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html) to get all documents.

```js
const myGroups = await admin.firestore().collection('groups').get()

return myGroups.docs.map(group => ({id: group.id, ...group.data()}))
```

Additionally, if you are trying to find groups where `playerId` is `userId`. Then you can use `where()` clause to narrow search results:

```js
const myGroups = await admin.firestore()
  .collection('groups')
  .where("playerId", "==", userId)
  .get()
```

You can read more about queries in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#node.js_1).

Comment: Hi friends,

I created a function for firebase, I need to filter docs where an arrayContainsAny a String but I get an error:
Exception from a finished function: ReferenceError: arrayContainsAny is not defined

my line:

await admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc('new').collection('pictures').where('tags', arrayContainsAny[wordTag]).get();

how can I achieve this? thanks in advance!